# Am trying to put radius on the second container but I can't in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As you can see in the picture, I need my page to have radius on the second container as in the picture.

[image]

I have tried to use different approach like using `BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(40))` but still can't make it to work.

Here is my widget.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Image.asset("images/page1.png"),
            )),
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(40))),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Save and",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Withdraw Money",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'you can find trainers',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 3,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'at our best trainers and help',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 3,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'and help you reacg the Top',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 3,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  height: 60,
                  width: 150,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.green),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text("NEXT")),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a property color to your container which you are giving radius.
I am giving it a red color.

```dart
Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(40)),
          color: Colors.red,
```

Now see the attached image.
It is rounded from one end, but as both background and foreground are white you can't see the effect.

**Picture of your implementation with color given to container**

[image: Picture of your implementation with color given to container]

Now you have seen what's happening.
you can give container width of infinity and change background color, or maybe you will need one more container.
Keeping in view the attached image, continue with your design.

Comment: thanks so much man you saved my day, I followed that and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `Stack` for body. I Will also recommend using `LayoutBuilder`  to get parent `constraints`.

The first child will be a background image and the last child will be a clickable widget. Widgets render priority is bottom to top on `Stack`.

**Result**

[image]

**So the build method will**

```dart
 return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                // you may not need this
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * .8,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  //replace with background image
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  foregroundPainter:
                      BoxPainterC(), // test using foregroundPainter
                  // painter: BoxPainterC(),
                  size: Size(
                    constraints.maxWidth,
                    constraints.maxHeight * .7,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: const Alignment(0, .7), //align text and button etc
                child: SizedBox(child: getCulmn()),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

UI could be done  without `CustomPaint`/`ClipPath` but we have to curve the top size as well, here comes `quadraticBezier` curve.

**Break Paints**

- 4 corners are mark as blue,
- 3 straits lines mark as Black,
- 1 top level Curve mark as Red,

[image]

**Painter Class**

Bottom may be handled by device's screen size, but I'm considering that is  out.

```dart
class BoxPainterC extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 3
      ..color = Colors.white
      // ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke // enalbe for understand purpose
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    Path path = Path();

    final cornerCurve = size.width * .1;
    final topCurveHeight = size.height * .1;

    path.moveTo(
        0, cornerCurve + topCurveHeight); //move little down + topCurve spaces
    path.lineTo(0, size.height * .9); // draw left line

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        0, size.height, cornerCurve, size.height); //bottom-left corner

    path.lineTo(size.width - cornerCurve, size.height); // bottom line

    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height, size.width,
        size.height - cornerCurve); // bottom right corner

    path.lineTo(size.width, cornerCurve + topCurveHeight); // left line

    //* topRightCorner:  without getting topCurve spaces
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width,
      topCurveHeight,
      size.width - (cornerCurve),
      topCurveHeight / 2,
    );

    // //* moving the draw point to get better understanding
    path.moveTo(0, topCurveHeight + cornerCurve);

    // //* topLeftCorner:  without getting topCurve spaces
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      0,
      topCurveHeight,
      cornerCurve,
      topCurveHeight / 2,
    );

    // //**TOP level Curve */
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width / 2,
      -topCurveHeight, // curve little more
      size.width - cornerCurve,
      topCurveHeight / 2,
    );

    canvas.drawPath(
      path,
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And **getColumn** is

```dart
  getCulmn() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Text(
          "Save and",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Text(
          "Withdraw Money",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        const Text(
          'you can find trainers',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          maxLines: 3,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 25,
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
          height: 60,
          width: 150,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.green),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text("NEXT")),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```